# как привязать домен к vps?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Искал, похожие вопросы задавались. Но я там не нашел ответа на мой вопрос.
В `ect/apache2` открыл `apache2.conf` и внес туда вот этот блок

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.name
DocumentRoot /home/user/domain.name/public_html/public
ServerName domain.name
</VirtualHost>
```

Убрал `errorlog` и `customlog` ибо из за них не запускался апач. Домен в данный момент переделигируется. Сейчас по айпи на сайт заходит. Вопрос: больше не надо не куда на сервере вписывать что то еще? Днс адреса или что то еще?

Comment: Пробовали сделать то, что написано в ошибке?

Comment: @andreymal гугли ошибку, не нашел точного ответа. Кто то говорит что апач с php7 что то там плохо совмести и надо установить мод под php7, кто то говорит что надо апач переустановить. Точного ответа не нашел

Comment: У вас вопрос как привязать домен или по ошибке Apache? Если интересует как привязать домен - то в домене указать IP адрес сервера, на котором находится Apache. Если вопрос по ошибке - то выполните `apachectl configtest`.

Comment: @Alex_01 вы на вопрос-то не ответили — пробовали сделать то, что написано в ошибке?

Comment: @МАН69К вот что выдал 
`AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK`

Comment: @andreymal я не понимаю что он мне говорит сделать)

Comment: @МАН69К вопрос в том, как привязать домен. В рамках этого вопроса, выходит эта ошибка)

Comment: @Alex_01: как именно Apache перезапускали? Какой командой?

Comment: @МАН69К `sudo service apache2 restart`, сейчас я убрал код который в вопросе из `apache2.conf`. У меня теперь только в `sites-available` и `sites-enabled` лежит один конфиг на один сайт. И по ip этот сайт открывается

Comment: @Alex_01: а через `apachectl restart` пробовали? Были ошибки?

Comment: @МАН69К нет, сейчас попробую

Comment: @МАН69К Вписал опять тот код что в вопросе, проверил конфигтестом, он ругался на директорию с логами. Убрал эти 2 строки с логами, конфигтест прошел, потом перезапустил апач командой `apachectl restart`  вот эта ошибка вылезла 
`AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Comment: поставил `ServerName localhost` в `apache2.conf` ошибка изчезла. Апач нормально перезагрузился. Получается все? Домен еще не переделигировался на днс яндекса, как переделигируется, сайт будит доступен? Или куда то на сервере днс адреса еще надо указать?

Comment: @Alex_01: Без error_log вам будет тяжело, лучше проверьте что там с ними было не так (может права не те на каталог или путь абсолютный укажите). В теории - всё. Что бы проверить - создайте у себя в /etc/hosts (если ваш рабочий компьютер - linux) строку вида `IP_сервера имя_домена` - так вы сможете открывать ваш сайт с вашего сервера не зависимо от настроек домена и проверить его работу.

Comment: @МАН69К домен делигировал, но по нему сайт не открывается( странно что при проверки whois, стоит ´Домен: ns1.domain.name., IP: 77.88.8.8´ и ´Второй NS:   Домен: ns2.domain.name., IP: 77.88.8.1´, ведь у меня на сервере нет ни какого днс сервера. Не должно же быть так?

Comment: @Alex_01: "не открывается" это очень общее описание. Назовите ваш домен.

Comment: @Alex_01: вы, похоже, просто указали для домена DNS Яндекса, но не создали на них (на стороне Яндекса) никаких записей для домена.

Comment: @МАН69К да,я на стороне яндекса ничего не указал. И что теперь делать?) через яндекс вебмастера указывать или как?

Comment: @Alex_01: я DNS Яндекса не использовал, как на них создаются настройки не знаю. Но судя по их справке, это должно быть здесь - https://pdd.yandex.ru/. Почитайте справку Яндекса на тему "Делегирование домена на серверы Яндекса".

Comment: @МАН69К вроде разобрался. Спасибо) напишите в ответе, я как лучший ответ выберу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привязку домена к VPS можно разделить на два этапа:

- Настройка Apache;
- Направление домена на сервер.

**Настройка Apache** заключается в добавлении в конфигурацию сервера настроек сайта в блоке `<VirtualHost *:80> ... </VirtualHost>` с директивами `DocumentRoot`, `ServerName` и прочими необходимыми.

После добавлении конфигурации - её нужно проверить. Это делается командой `apachectl configtest`. Ответ должен быть `Syntax OK`. В случае наличия ошибок синтаксиса - будет указано в какой строке какого файла они есть.

Если ошибок нет - нужно перезапустить Apache для применения новых настроек. Это можно сделать через `apachectl restart`, либо, если сервер уже обслуживает какие-то сайты, через `apachectl graceful`. Во втором случае веб-сервер дождётся завершения обработки текущих запросов (а не оборвёт их) и новую конфигурацию применит к новым запросам.

**Направление домена на сервер**, в случае использования DNS Яндекса, выполняется по [этой](https://yandex.ru/support/pdd/delegir.xml) инструкции. На стороне Яндекса управление доменом находится на странице https://pdd.yandex.ru/. Для работы сайта необходима A запись (с указанимем IPv4 адреса сервера) и, по желанию, AAAA запись для IPv6 адреса (разумеется при его наличии). На стороне регистратора домена необходимо указать следующие NS: `dns1.yandex.net.` и `dns2.yandex.net.`.